# How can I use my class within a function in my wordpress plugin's index.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin I am working on, everything is working fine but everything is in my index.php file, all logic is in there. I am currently refactoring and created some classes in separate files. I am unable to currently use these classes inside my plugins functions.

In my index.php file I have a function that handles a pricing shortcode.
I also have a pricing class, however I am unable to use it,

```php
$price = new Price();
function pricingShortcodeFunction(){
    return $price->showPrice(); //Should return value but not working in the function
}
```

Comment: I am autoloading the classes using Composer/PSR-4 if I put that first line instantiating the Price class inside of the shortcode function, it works fine, but when I instantiate the class outside of the function it does not work.

Comment: ^ That is because variables are scoped within functions in PHP. You need to call `global $price` in your  function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)